# HTML string does not get verified

Tags: c#, watin

**These spaces are not added by me on HTML SIDE and i cannot edit HTML
I want to know what should my comparison string?**

I am using watin to automate website testing process but I am unable to encounter only one button.Every other works

watin searches content by name /values /id and many more and works fine but when i see the value of the submit button that i need to be clicked it has some breaks &nsbp so i think they are playing some role

Here is the html:

```
<span class='button'><input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" /></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class='button'><input type="button" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Back&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" onclick="history.back(-1)" /></span>
```

and here is the code to search

```
  browser.Button(WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")).Click();
```

what can be done??

Comment: This is really not fair, that people downvoting this question, when they probably don't even know what WatiN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use entities with WatiN.

This code will work, **but you have to use real non-breaking space character**:

```
browser.Button(
    WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue(
        "   Login   ")).Click();
```

This is probably inconvenient, but you could use (after adding reference to `System.Web`) `HttpUtility` class:

```
browser.Button(
    WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue(
        System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"))).Click();
```

But, if I were you, I would just go with `Regex`:

```
browser.Button(
    WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue(
        new Regex(@"^\s*Login\s*$"))).Click();
```

or even `new Regex("Login")`.

Interesting thing: If you ever will have to `Find.ByText` you don't have to bother so much, and you can use regular space (ie. not exactly non-breaking space). That's because native IE `IHTMLElement::getAttribute` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280(VS.85).aspx) converts `&nbsp;` from `innertext` attribute to regular spaces, but from `value`, `id` etc. it doesn't (`&nbsp;` are converted to real non-breaking spaces - `0xA0`)

Comment: Man you are great.This worked more than wellbrowser.Button(
    WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue(
        new Regex(@"^\s*Login\s*$"))).Click();

I want to have some knowledge about @"^\s*Login\s*$" what dose this string mean??

Comment: This is just a regular expression used by .Net `Regex` class. It's a big topic if you don't know anything about that. In short, this particular expression - `^\s*Login\s*$` - will match any value that starts and ends with whitespace and has `Login` part inside.

Answer (score 3):

-- **Suggestion** -- (i.e. too big for a comment)

You shouldn't use `&nbsp;` to add spaces to the submit button.  Rather, you should use CSS to style the button to your liking.  So you would have something like:

```
input[type=button] {
    padding:10px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

By the same token, this could eliminate any of the issues you're having with selecting the button.  It could be an issue of *encodings* breaking with watin and as a result, doing this with CSS will make debugging the issue much cleaner and much easier.

**Edit:**
Have you tried searching by ID as opposed to by value?  ID's are supposed to be unique on a page, so if it doesn't find it by those means, then that's one issue that can be rules out.  It could also be the fact that you're searching for a button.  A `<button>` is not the same as a `<input type="button">`.

**Edit 2:** Even though the issue was due to encodings breaking, I still recommend you reset that button to reset the text (removing all the non breaking spaces) and attach an id/name to it.  The reason being for internationalization purposes - and if for some reason you modify the size of the button in the designer, or i18n the app and the text is different, your test will break.

Comment: Afnan just edited his post: it's not his html. (-1, let me know when you change the post)

Comment: Even without edit it's obvious, that op is using WatiN, so if somebody  don't know what it is, I think he/she shouldn't answer the question. -1, because answer is unrelated to question.

Comment: Fixed - added the title :). And I don't believe my answer is unrelated to the question.  It WAS an issue with the encodings and I think it would be best if Afnan attempted to search by id as well as using CSS for the stylings (see edit 2).

Comment: Why are you saying the issue was encoding? Besides, he can't change the html.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you really like spaces! I would remove those and use padding/margins like html was designed to be used.  Then you wont need all those spaces and you can assign a proper value to your button which watiN will recognize.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the `&nbsp;` in the HTML source is actually an escaped version of the special character that represents a none breaking space. So in you C# source, you'll probably need that character instead of the html entity code. I think you can find the code of that character by using this button to submit a GET form. It will show the escaped character code in the url.

Of course it is better not to put the spaces in there at all. You should give the button a padding using CSS instead.